# controller is not recognizing @requestparam from ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-boot

i am trying to send json from ajax to springboot controller but getting error [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Item[] parameter 'myJsonString[]' is not present]

below is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/DBA_TOOLS/admin/tracker",
    data: {myJsonString:myJsonString},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data){
        if(data.status == "SUCCESS"){
            alert("AJAX request successfully completed:"+JSON.stringify(data));
        }else{
            console.log('Error Msg'+JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        console.log('Error Msg'+data.message+''+JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.status);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
    complete: function() {

    }
});
```

below is my controller

```
@PostMapping(value="/tracker")
public int traker(@RequestParam(value="myJsonString[]") Item[] myJsonString){    

    System.out.println("getting somethig from tracker");
    
    int count=0;
    try{
        for(Item item : myJsonString){
           System.out.println("User  is updating item id "+item.getName());
           //count+= ggProcessRepository.changeAlert(row,isActive);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception Occured"+e);
    }
    return count;
}
```

i tried with requestparam required false and its let the block working but how to get the ajax data to my requestparam is the challenge for me.

in browser debug i see the form data getting send is -->  myJsonString: [{"name":"product 2","price":20,"quantity":1},{"name":"product 3","price":30,"quantity":1}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you change it to:

```
traker(@RequestParam(value="myJsonString")
```

Comment: this changed my error to : [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.munish.app.model.Item[]'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.munish.app.model.Item': no matching editors or conversion strategy found], i think i will be able to solve it , will post the solution if got